# Gyroscope Parallax Effect In Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, parallax-scrolling

I want to make a parallax effect in Unity 3D with gyroscope like the one on this site:
http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

I found an [asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11806), but it is too expensive.

So I need a script which I can set to the GameObject, so it would move depending phone's gyroscope.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so hard to find some sources from google;

Parallax effect (logic): 
[How do I implement parallax scrolling in 2D?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-can-i-implement-parallax-scrolling-into-my-2d-game?rq=1)

Gyroscope: 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html 
 http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-gyro.html

Answer (score 1):

You are asking like "Gimme a script dammit!". Well, i can't give you a script. But i can tell you how to write your own.

Parallax effect basically means moving background objects slower than foreground ones to create a fake 3D (or depth) effect.

So if you have a vector that represents foregound velocity like:

```
//values and names are example
Vector3 foregroundVelocity = new Vector3(10,0,0);
```

Than you can use these vectors for background velocity (not limited to these):

```
//values and names are example
Vector3 backgroundVelocity = new Vector3(7,0,0);
Vector3 evenMoreBackgroundVelocity = new Vector3(5,0,0);
Vector3 farFarAwayVelocity = new Vector3(3,0,0);
Vector3 rightInFrontOfHorizonLineVelocity = new Vector3(1,0,0);
```

Then you can get gyro input from Unity's own [Gyrpscope](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html) class, as @AhmetZambak mentioned, and just move your sprites (or gameObjects) according to magnitudes of corresponding angles, like:

```
//pseoudocode
Vector3 eulerGyroAngles = /*your input reading code*/;
gameObject.transform.position = (eulerGyroAngles.y, eulerGyroAngles.x, 0) * (corresponding magnitude vector);
```

Comment: Why do you use eulerGyroAngles ? Why not just Quaternion

Comment: @Drukalo If you know how to deal with them, go ahead. I personally prefer euler angles.

Comment: I mean i really don't know how to make object move with gyroscope like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4xuMh2rkJQ

Answer (score 0):

[Unity-Gyroscope-Parallax](https://github.com/IvanMurzak/Unity-Gyroscope-Parallax)

There is a free plugin for gyroscope parallax effects, it can move object position and/or rotate object in space via gyroscope input data as gravity vector or as a movement in space direction.

[image: Object movement in space based on gyroscope]